# R interpolate rows with different start and end columns

Tags: r, interpolation

I have multiple data sets that look like the following:

| country | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.5 | NA | 0.7 | 0.6 | 0.8 | NA |
| USA | NA | NA | NA | 0.1 | 0.4 | NA | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| France | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.8 | NA | NA | 1.0 | 1.3 |
| Belgium | NA | 0.1 | NA | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.5 | NA | NA |

I want to interpolate horizontally, starting from the first existing value until the last existing value. In essence, NAs at the start and NAs at the end should stay NAs, but NAs in the middle should be interpolated. I have been trying to think of a possible solution, but nothing comes up.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.approx`:

```r
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) na.approx(x, na.rm = F)))
```

or even without apply:

```r
replace(df, -1, t(na.approx(t(df[-1]))))
```

output

```r
  country `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007`
1 Germany    0.1    0.2    0.5    0.6  0.7    0.6      0.8   NA  
2 USA       NA     NA     NA      0.1  0.4    0.4      0.4    0.1
3 France     0.4    0.3    0.5    0.8  0.867  0.933    1      1.3
4 Belgium   NA      0.1    0.3    0.5  0.6    0.5     NA     NA
```

---

Note that a `tidy` format might be easier for further wrangling here:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, id)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value = na.approx(value, na.rm = F))
```